# Using Shopify JS Buy SDK, unable to remove variant item from cart

Tags: javascript, shopify, shopify-javascript-buy-sdk

I have a button to remove an item from the cart on my cart page, but I'm receiving this error: *Variable $lineItemIds of type [ID!]! was provided invalid value*.

I've gone through the GraphQL list and tried every single ID, title, and variant, but it still gives me this error. Which ID should I be using and how should I format the ID correctly?

```
 $('.remove-item').on('click', function() {
    const lineItems = checkout.attrs.lineItems;
    const checkoutId = 'gid://shopify/Checkout/xxxxxxxxxxx';
    var dataid = this.getAttribute('data-id');
    var varid = btoa(lineItems[dataid].variant.id);
    var lineItemsToRemove = [{
        variantId: varid,
        quantity: 1
    }];
    client.checkout.removeLineItems(checkoutId, lineItemsToRemove).then((checkout) => {
    });
});
```

Comment: You are trying to use this 

    variantId: bid

But no where in your function is bid given a value. Use the variant ID.

Comment: Thanks. I've updated the variable and it is still giving the same error.

Comment: You see confused here. Checkout is not the cart. If you want to remove an item from the cart, you call the cart update endpoint with the variant ID and quantity to remove. This has nothing to do with checkout. Once you are in checkout, you don't get to alter item counts. Too late for that.

Comment: The documentation for the JS Buy SDK says that line items can be removed via the checkout using this method. 
https://shopify.github.io/js-buy-sdk/#removing-line-items

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After reviewing the documentation, I realized I was adding an id attribute. It should just pass the plain ID.

```
var lineItemsToRemove = [
    varid2
];
```

instead of

```
var lineItemsToRemove = [{
    id:varid2
}];
```